# how to make sysfs changes persistent in centos 7 (systemd)

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

Trying to fix up the fn keys on my apple keyboard on CentOS 7, I've set

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
options hid_apple fnmode=2
```

and yet after a reboot

```
$ cat /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
1
```

Suggestions on the internet include running update-initramfs, which doesn't seem to exist on Centos 7, and doing the "echo 2 >> /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode" in /etc/rc.local, which of course doesn't exist at all any more under systemd.

What's the right way to persist that setting?

Comment: Oh, that was a typo creating the post, sorry. It's "fnmode" in hid_apple.conf and in the filename under /sys/module/.... I've fixed the post, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 ways in which you can achieve this:

1. rc.local (Still works, remember to chmod +x after adding your lines)
2. systemd
3. udev rules (My own preferred)

With systemd:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/hid_apple_fnmode_set.service 
[Unit]
Description=Set Apple keyboard fn mode
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode'

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Followed by this to make the service run at boot.

```
sudo systemctl enable hid_apple_fnmode_set.service
```

With udev rules:

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hid_apple.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="module", DRIVER=="hid_apple", ATTR{parameters/fnmode}="2"
```

The systemd script and udev rules are put together with some wild guesses, might take some tweaking to work. The following commands can help adjust and debug the udev rule:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/module/hid_apple

udevadm test /sys/module/hid_apple/
```

Comment: Could you give a hint about what the systemd solution would look like? Or at least a pointer to it? This is my first time on a systemd system.

Comment: I've amended the answer so see if those works for you.

Comment: Wow, what a great answer, you just totally bootstrapped my understanding of both systemd and udev. Thanks, @Angelos!

Comment: `KERNEL=="hid_apple" SUBSYSTEM=="module", DRIVER=="", ATTR{parameters/fnmode}="2"` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Use tmpfiles.d mechanism, place, for example, apple-hid.conf to /etc/tmpfiles.d with folowing content

```
w /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode - - - - 2
```

Comment: This is a brilliant hack, and also ansible-friendly. After creating the file, ensure to run `systemd-tmpfiles --create` to have `systemd-tmpfiles` write into `/sys`. Thanks for the tip! 